# Breadcrumbs "You are here" gone in Joomla

Tags: joomla, module, joomla2.5, breadcrumbs

I have a problem displaying the "you are here" text in the breadcrumb module for Joomla 2.5. I have set "Show "You are here"" to yes! but it still dossent show any thing on the site.
Any good idea how to solve this problem.
I have been searching for solutions, but i can only find ppl having trouble getting rid of it.

Comment: have you checked `templates/YOURTEMPLATE/html/mod_breadcrumbs` to see if there is a template override for the module which could possible be changing it?

Comment: _or_ you could have a language override for the string MOD_BREADCRUMBS_HERE . Also, you mention it won't show "you are here", but it does show the breadcrumb links? else you need to enable the module and make sure it's assigned to all the pages you want it on.

Comment: Nice, it was my template overriding it. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

you can set

```
Show "You are here" - Yes
Show Home           - Yes
Text for Home Entry - Home
Show Last           - Yes
Text Separator      - >
```

above all setting done in Breadcrumbs - module in joomla.

then save & close , now check with clear cache of your site.